# Pass JSON data returned from fetch() to .map inside a const

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, mdbreact

Right now my code is pulling its JSON from a file, I am trying to have it pull the data from an API instead, I have successfully printed the array from the API to the console, however when I try to use the .map function on the data I pulled, I receive an error saying that the variable holding my array is unidentified.

Working code that prints array to console:

```
import React from 'react';
import { MDBDataTable } from 'mdbreact';
import API_Data from '../myJSON_Data.json';

const DatatablePage = () => {

    fetch('https://api')
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
    });

  const data = {
    columns: [
      {
        label: 'Name',
        field: 'name',
        sort: 'asc',
        width: 150
      }
    ],
    rows: API_Data.map(API_Data => {
      return {
        state: API_Data.name
      }
    })
  };

  return (
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>            
                <h1>Data from API</h1>
                <MDBDataTable
                    striped
                    bordered
                    hover
                    data={data}
                />
                </div>                            
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  );  
}

export default DatatablePage;
```

What I have tried:

```
import React from 'react';
import { MDBDataTable } from 'mdbreact';

const DatatablePage = () => {
    var apiData;
    fetch('https://api')
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        apiData = data;
    });

  const data = {
    columns: [
      {
        label: 'Name',
        field: 'name',
        sort: 'asc',
        width: 150
      }
    ],
    rows: apiData.map(apiData => {
      return {
        state: apiData.name
      }
    })
  };

  return (
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>            
                <h1>Data from API</h1>
                <MDBDataTable
                    striped
                    bordered
                    hover
                    data={data}
                />
                </div>                            
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  );  
}

export default DatatablePage;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not do `async(side-effect)` call in render(here functional component). For that use `useEffect` and set state using `useState`. Read more about hooks.

Here is the sample, You read and modify according to ur need. 
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { MDBDataTable } from "mdbreact";

const DatatablePage = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://api")
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((res) => {
        const data = {
          columns: [
            {
              label: "Name",
              field: "name",
              sort: "asc",
              width: 150,
            },
          ],
          rows: res.map((apiData) => ({state: apiData.name})),
        };
        setData(data);
      });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <h1>Data from API</h1>
            <MDBDataTable striped bordered hover data={data} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DatatablePage;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try putting the fetch() in a promise and calling the .map when the promise resolves or alternatively assign a const data within the same fetch method.